# Symfony: how can I load a .css in a page without layout?

Tags: layout, symfony1

i have the typical cover page with the logining form that doesn't have the layout with the menu bar that the intern pages of the site have.

So i have this line in view.yml:

```
signinSuccess:
  has_layout:     false
```

As you know, in this way the .css are not loaded. So what can i do to load the .css?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Every template in your website should have a layout, unless the action returns non-HTML. Use Coronatus' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958084/symfony-how-can-i-load-a-css-in-a-page-without-layout/2958810#2958810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different named layout.

```
signinSuccess:
     layout:     "some_other_file"
```

Then create the layout file and voila.